# Cocoa custom view add & positioning it inside NSPopover

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xamarin, mono

I'm using NSpopover on a status bar app, as a fly out menu on Mac OSx Yosemite. I add a few custom views inside NSPopver. Which will appear and disappear based on button clicks or other events.

The problem I face is that I just cannot stack and place the custom views inside NSPopover, one below the other in an orderly fashion. The following code for eg (C# code run using Xamarin) creates and positions each view under NSpopover, but it would not place the views where it logically should be -

```
View1.SetFrameSize(new SizeF(20, 20));
View1.SetFrameOrigin(0,0);
NSPopover.ContentView.InnerView.AddSubview(View1);
View2.SetFrameSize(new SizeF(20, 20));
View2.SetFrameOrigin(0,20);
NSPopover.ContentView.InnerView.AddSubview(View2);
View3.SetFrameSize(new SizeF(20, 20));
View3.SetFrameOrigin(0,40);
NSPopover.ContentView.InnerView.AddSubview(View3);
NSPopover.Behavior = NSPopoverBehavior.Transient;
NSPopover.Appearance = NSPopoverAppearance.HUD;
```

This code should stack 3 views straight inside a view within a NSPopover.
But it adds the first one without issues, but the next 2 views(or more) just gets placed randomly anywhere within "NSPopover.ContentView", or completely out of the canvas or visibility, without any rhyme or reason.

I tried different combinations of SetFrameOrigin, and it just makes things worse. Is the auto-layout settings of the views is messing with the placement of the views?

I'm new to cocoa dev, and any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to set a cgcolor ([nscolor yellowcolor].CGColor) of your views (e.g. view.layer ) so you can see what's happening.

Comment: I did try adding colored borders to the inner views, and that is how I figured, that the views are getting placed randomly.

Comment: So it's just the origin or the size is random? Can you check your code also doesn't call initwithcoder (source of randomness)

Comment: It is the placement which is random. It takes the exact size given.

Comment: I removed any references to initwithcoder as well, with no difference.

Comment: So you have to debug in lldb, set a breakpoint and verify what values you see in awakeFromNib. What is strange in Xamarin (I am cocoa dev) is that i do not see in your code any reference to viewcontroller that handles popover